# Multiple remote validation attribute in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, attributes

I've got a problem that I can't figure how to solve.
I have a remote validation in a model, just like this:

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Social Security Number:")]
[Remote("IsSocialSecurityNumberValid", "Applicant", ErrorMessage = "Invalid.")]
public string SocialSecurityNumber { get; set; }
```

But there's another validation that I would like to apply, that is:

```
[Remote("SocialSecurityNumberExists", "Applicant", ErrorMessage = "Already exists.")]
```

But mvc doesn't let me add two remote attributes.
How could I solve that?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Create one "general" remote validation Action, that return the combined result of the `IsSocialSecurityNumberValid` and `SocialSecurityNumberExists` methods.

Comment: But for each case i want a different message... how would i do that?

Comment: I can't think of a simple solution that does not require tinkering with the metadata or some sort of JavaScript manipulation. If a generic "SSN invalid or existing" message is out of the question, you would need to resort to metadata manipulation, which, in controller, is not a thrill...

Comment: Well, javascript doesn't seems to me a bad approach. So do you think it's a good idea to call the server twice in a javascript function and show the correct validation through two different actions? I had thought about that, but was afraid of doing some "kludge"...

Comment: Why twice? Just call it once (on the "general" remote validation Action) and expect an "error message" as result. Then set it on your property.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See below an example:

```
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Social Security Number:")]
    [Remote("ValidSocialSecurityNumber", "Applicant")]
    public string SocialSecurityNumber { get; set; }
```

Your Action

```
public JsonResult ValidSocialSecurityNumber([Bind(Prefix = "SocialSecurityNumber ")] string ssn) 
{
    if (!isSocialSecurityNumberValid) 
    {
        return Json("Invalid.", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    if (isSocialSecurityNumberExists) 
    {
        return Json("Already exists.", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: But I think in this case I'm still validating only one of the cases. The additional attribute should be a different one...

Comment: hi @GiordanoGiuliano, I got it know. Let me update my answer.

Comment: Using only one remote validation function, you can return different error messages.

Comment: Oh nice one. Pretty simple. I'm gonna try it and tell you if it works. Thank you very much for the help. I'm still a starter at MVC. ^_^

Comment: No problems. We are all learning. You need to implement isSocialSecurityNumberValid and isSocialSecurityNumberExists before use them. hope it helps.

Comment: Tested it. Worked wonderfully. Thanks so much fellow. I'm learning a lot with you here from Stack Overflow ^_^

Comment: Pretty easy and simple. Thanks.